# get embed dashboard with roles and permissions in superset

Tags: permissions, roles, apache-superset

I am trying to embed dashboard in superset based on the roles and permissions created in superset application roles.

I had created a role and given certain permission and assigned to specific user. But while embeding in superset, that particular user is having the permission of 'view query' option in chart controls even though I didn't assigned that in permission. But when I log in to superset directly with that user, I can see those roles and permissions are applying over there but not in Embed Dashboard. Can anyone help me on this?

**I am using superset version - 2.0.1**

**superset logs:**

2023-02-13 16:31:00,516:ERROR:root:'GuestUser' object has no attribute 'get_user_id'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/main_project/binary_superset_file/binary_ss_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/**init**.py", line 86, in wraps
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/main_project/binary_superset_file/binary_ss_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/superset/utils/log.py", line 245, in wrapper
value = f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/main_project/binary_superset_file/binary_ss_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/superset/dashboards/filter_state/api.py", line 98, in post
return super().post(pk)
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/main_project/binary_superset_file/binary_ss_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/superset/views/base_api.py", line 83, in wraps
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/main_project/binary_superset_file/binary_ss_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/superset/temporary_cache/api.py", line 76, in post
key = self.get_create_command()(args).run()
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/main_project/binary_superset_file/binary_ss_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/superset/temporary_cache/commands/create.py", line 35, in run
return self.create(self._cmd_params)
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/main_project/binary_superset_file/binary_ss_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/superset/dashboards/filter_state/commands/create.py", line 41, in create
entry: Entry = {"owner": get_owner(actor), "value": value}
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/main_project/binary_superset_file/binary_ss_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/superset/key_value/utils.py", line 70, in get_owner
return user.get_user_id() if not user.is_anonymous else None
AttributeError: 'GuestUser' object has no attribute 'get_user_id'
2023-02-13 16:31:00,533:INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2023 16:31:00] "POST /api/v1/dashboard/11/filter_state?tab_id=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -

**And I am getting the following error in browser console.**

POST http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/v1/dashboard/11/filter_state?tab_id=1 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/v1/dashboard/11/filter_state?tab_id=1', redirected: false, status: 500, ok: false, …}